# polling to server to request information about server.Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, client-server

**System Overview:** Client on Ubuntu

**SDK/Language :**  QT/C++

**Restriction**: Cannot access server code.

**Problem:**
 I need to poll server from client at regular interval and expect server to respond back with response message. The expected message is quite long string.

**Description :**
I have already implemented Qt Client that establish connection with non-qt server. The  software  is single threaded on both client and server & works as expected.It means  User ask client  to send some request command to server and server response back. Now with that I need to poll server at regular interval to ask for its status information. 
I am looking for suggestion on how to implement that.*[ Note : I am not looking for source code but just bit fo hint and tools or libraries to use]*

There are few options which I thought

**1)** *Use for loop in code with QTimer that sends status_request to server and server response back*

*****DisAdv:*****
i) what will happen if user and New loop send query at same time.?

ii) Is it possible that for loop will eat up all resources?

***2)*** Use different thread for polling ? what you guys think about that? With current requirement do you think introducing new thread is a good idea?

**3)** Any other better and feasible solution?

Comment: You really need to understand what an event loop is, and how to write asynchronous code. Forget about "waiting" for anything. Instead, you get notified of and have your slots run when things happen, such as a network request finishing, or a timer expiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use for loop in code with QTimer

Why do you need `QTimer` in `for` loop?
Use [`QTimer::singleShot`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot).

Send request to server at program start and execute `QTimer::singleShot()` each time after server response. It will be better than sending requests each *N* milliseconds.

Do not forget about network errors.